# Как удалить объект спрайта Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, спрайт

Мне нужно удалять спрайт из массива, когда он выходит за границу...
Вот код:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Защита")
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("images/sheald.png"))
fon = pygame.image.load("images/fon.png")


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, y, speed, image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(70, y + 20))
        self.speed = speed

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speed
        win.blit(self.image, self.rect)


playerY = 70
playerX = 20
bull = []
bulletsNumber = 10
FPS = 60


def shoot():
    global bulletsNumber
    if bulletsNumber > 0:
        bulletsNumber -= 1
        bullet = Bullet(playerY, 2, 'images/bullet.png')
        bull.append(bullet)


def window():
    win.blit(fon, (0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (236, 218, 103), (playerX, playerY, 40, 40))
    for bul in bull:
        bul.update()
        if bul.rect.x >= 700:
            **тут нужно удалить объект**
```

window - это обновление экрана
shoot -  создание объекта

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
имя_массива.remove(нужный_фрагмент_массива)
имя_массива.pop(номер_в_массиве)
```

например:

```
 a = [1,2,3]
 a.remove(1)
 a - [2,3]
 a.pop(0)
 a - [3]
```